# Adding aggregation that exclude all except one column in Polars Python group by

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a big df (60 M rows) and I need to do some groupings and aggregations

This is a sample like my data

```
dic = {
      'Attr1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
      'Attr2' : ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'],
      'Val1' : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    }
df = pl.DataFrame(dic)
df
shape: (12, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬──────┐
│ Attr1 ┆ Attr2 ┆ Val1 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ i64  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ A     ┆ X     ┆ 1    │
│ A     ┆ X     ┆ 2    │
│ A     ┆ Y     ┆ 3    │
│ A     ┆ Y     ┆ 4    │
│ …     ┆ …     ┆ …    │
│ C     ┆ X     ┆ 9    │
│ C     ┆ X     ┆ 10   │
│ C     ┆ Y     ┆ 11   │
│ C     ┆ Y     ┆ 12   │
└───────┴───────┴──────┘
```

I am trying to get the max value per Attr1 with the grouping per Attr1 and Attr2

```
df.group_by(
    ['Attr1' , 'Attr2'], maintain_order=True
    ).agg(
        pl.col('Attr1').count().alias('count'),
        pl.col('Val1').max().alias('MAX')
        )
shape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ Attr1 ┆ Attr2 ┆ count ┆ MAX │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ u32   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ A     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 2   │
│ A     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 4   │
│ B     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 6   │
│ B     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ C     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 10  │
│ C     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 12  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘
```

But I need to get the following output

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ Attr1 ┆ Attr2 ┆ count ┆ MAX │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ u32   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ A     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 4   │
│ A     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 4   │
│ B     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ B     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ C     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 12  │
│ C     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 12  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘
```

I could separate the DF into two DFs then group then merge but I am looking for the best optimized solution for high performance an low memory cost.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate things to optimize on. One is code elegance/brevity and the other is performance. Often we think that whichever solution is less code will also be better performance.

Given that you're using `max` and not an aggregation that depends on all the values, @alexp's answer is the best performance, utilizing a hybrid between a `group_by` context and a window. The `max` of the `max` approach gives the benefit of having the second group (namely of Attr1 only) be half the size of the first grouping.

In contrast, if you did only window functions it'd look like:

```
(
    df2
    .select(
        'Attr1','Attr2',
        pl.col('Attr1').count().over(['Attr1','Attr2']).alias('count'),
        pl.col('Val1').max().over('Attr1').alias('MAX')
        )
    .unique(['Attr1','Attr2'])
    .sort(['Attr1','Attr2'])
)
```

This might look nicer because it only has the single select context but it will perform worse as it doesn't get the max of max benefit. The use of `unique` at the end is because a window function will return all the original rows in contrast to a `group_by` which only returns the unique combinations of whatever is in the `group_by`. That's another reason to do a combination of a `group_by.agg` with a subsequent window function is to control which rows will be in the result set from the onset rather than paring them down at the end.

Another approach is the joining of group_bys. That would look like:

```
(
    df
    .group_by(['Attr1','Attr2'],maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col('Attr1').count().alias('count'))
    .join(
        df
        .group_by(['Attr1'],maintain_order=True)
        .agg(pl.col('Val1').max().alias('MAX')),
        on='Attr1'
    )
)
```

That one *looks* worse with the double `group_by` and the added complexity of the `join` makes it seem like it'd be slower than the nice elegant looking window function. The thing is that the window function is doing the same work, it's just not salient. It also doesn't get the same optimizations that `group_by` gets.

**Benchmark Time**

Say we start with

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
n=100_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame({
      'Attr1' : np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],n),
      'Attr2' : np.random.choice(['X','Y','Z'],n),
      'Val1' :  np.random.randint(0,100,n),
    }).sort(['Attr1','Attr2'])
```

and let's say we want to calculate the standard deviation instead of the max so our hybrid approach won't work.

We can do a pure window:

```
%%timeit
(
    df
    .select(
        'Attr1','Attr2',
        pl.col('Attr1').count().over(['Attr1','Attr2']).alias('count'),
        pl.col('Val1').std().over('Attr1').alias('MAX')
        )
    .unique(['Attr1','Attr2'])

)
6.91 s ± 466 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

or joined `group_by`s

```
%%timeit
(
    df
    .group_by(['Attr1','Attr2'],maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col('Attr1').count().alias('count')
        )
    .join(
        df
        .group_by(['Attr1'],maintain_order=True)
        .agg(pl.col('Val1').std().alias('MAX')),
        on='Attr1'
    )
)
3.81 s ± 302 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see the joined group_bys is almost twice as fast as using a pure window function.

Comment: That is a lot of work, thanks Dean. I am still not done benchmark the available solutions on my data yet

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for are ["Window functions"](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/window/) with which you can aggregate and get the result for your original dataframe.

```
(
    df
    .group_by(["Attr1", "Attr2"], maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col("Attr1").count().alias("count"), 
        pl.col("Val1").max().alias("MAX")
        )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("MAX").max().over("Attr1")
        )
    )



 shape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ Attr1 ┆ Attr2 ┆ count ┆ MAX │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ u32   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ A     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 4   │
│ A     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 4   │
│ B     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ B     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ C     ┆ X     ┆ 2     ┆ 12  │
│ C     ┆ Y     ┆ 2     ┆ 12  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Comment: This works because the max of the max is still the max. If you were doing, for instance, `std` then this wouldn't work as you'd be doing the std, first of the group attr1/attr2, then the std of that which is very different from the std just over attr1. This isn't meant as a criticism of the answer, it's just a note about the extensibility of a window after a group_by.